# anyone know a good cheap asp.net mvc3 webhost?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm looking for an asp.net webhost to use, not looking for anything particularly fancy, just something to test some stuff.

It will need to support sql databses...

Comment: Can you tell more about the specs you want?

Comment: hmm.. submitted a generic answer for now.

Comment: @MohamedMeligy just need one domain and unlimited sql databases, so long as it runs as expected it should be fine.

Comment: I think it's hard to get unlimited SQL databases under shared hosting (if only scoped to good hosting companies). Maybe reseller hosting.

Comment: Generally, plans for shared hosting are 1-5 DB per account, with various storage limits as well for total databases.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: The other post is nice as general guidance, but, a platform specific query (and even entire market) requires a post per platform though I "think".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the good hosting companies in the Microsoft space:

Just to mention a few ...

- [SoftSys Hosting](http://bit.ly/SoftSys) - my personal recommendation. The one I used personally
- [Accuwebhosting](http://www.accuwebhosting.com/windows-webhosting.htm) - the closest to SoftSys in reviews/specs etc

You can look for special offers and customize filter per requirements you want in the host from:
[microsoft.com/web/hosting](http://microsoft.com/web/hosting)

**Update:**

The best plans to find special web hosting offers in general is Web Hosting Talk forums. Check [Shared Hosting Offers](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?s=04b04802cfbec954edfce7d828090c3a&f=4) and [Reseller Hosting Offers](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?s=04b04802cfbec954edfce7d828090c3a&f=130), or write a new post with your requirements in the [general Windows Hosting section](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/forumdisplay.php?s=04b04802cfbec954edfce7d828090c3a&f=126).

If you want unlimited SQL DBs, maybe think about VPS as well. If for VPS, [SoftSys Hosting](http://bit.ly/SoftSys) is the best one in the affordable VPS space.

Comment: +softsys - i have a windows vps with them for $39/month. amazing bandwidth. great service.